# Adding some vertical spacing between button and textbox in Coffeescript

Tags: html, css, button, textbox, coffeescript

I am working with some Coffeescript markup which I pretty much have no experience in. I added an input box under a button, however, there is no spacing between the button and the text box:

```
  div class=("alert alert-info" if @password_reset_sent)
    a.btn.btn-default href="/my/path/" lk-data-method="post" Send reset link
    - if @password_reset_sent
      | &nbsp;&nbsp;
      i.fa.fa-check<>
      | Password reset link has been sent.
      - if flash["reset_url"]
        input.form-control value=flash["reset_url"]
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I would like if there is some additional space between the button and the input, like this:

[image]

I don't want to use any in-line CSS markup nor fiddle around with some additional CSS, because I know this front-end framework has some layout things I can write to add a little space.. ~~Like a new div?~~

EDIT:

Tried to add a new div like this. Didn't work.

```
  div class=("test")
    - if flash["reset_url"]
      input.form-control value=flash["reset_url"]
```

EDIT 2:

Tried this too:

```
  | &lt;br/&gt;
  - if flash["reset_url"]
      input.form-control value=flash["reset_url"]
```

Comment: Does `<br>` work?

Comment: Tried both `br` and `&lt;br/&gt;`, but doesn't work.

Comment: Try adding an empty div.. Empty divs don't have any height, so you need to add some.